# Replace substring with sed

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I have a string like this :

```
test:blabla
```

And with sed, I want to replace what's after the ':' with something else.

I can manage to replace a word, but not the one after the ':'. I searched on the internet for the answer, but I didn't found anything.

Any help ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use: `sed 's/:.*/:replaceword/'`

```
$ echo test:blabla | sed 's/:.*/:replaceword/'
test:replaceword
```

Or for the situation `test test:blabla test` where you only want to replace the word following `:` use  `sed 's/:[^ ]*/:replaceword/'`:

```
$ echo "test test:blabla test" | sed 's/:[^ ]*/:replaceword/'
test test:replaceword test

# Use the g flag for multiple matches on a line
$ echo "test test:blabla test test:blah2" | sed 's/:[^ ]*/:replaceword/g'
test test:replaceword test test:replaceword
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> echo $SER2
test:blabla
> echo $SER2 | sed 's/\([^:]*:\).*/\1replace/g'
test:replace
>
```