# Linux vi File Contents Modifying

Tags: linux, unix, sed, vi

Suppose I have these in a file called test:

```
u001:x:comp111:mark_henry
u002:x:comp321:zack_mike
u003:x:comp132:chris_white
```

And I want to open that file go to the line that has `chris_white` and change it to `chris_brown` so it becomes `u003:x:comp132:chris_brown`. I'm thinking to use the `sed` command to do so but I'm not sure how.

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid an answer. Here is a small sampling of duplicates: [Using 'sed' to find and replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159367/56041), [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/56041), [Find and replace text within a file using commands](https://askubuntu.com/q/20414), [Using grep and sed to find and replace a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178498/608639), [Replace substring with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14194702/608639), etc.

Comment: I'm baffled someone upvoted this question since an upvote indicates *"this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, below method can replace all occurrences of `chris_white` to `chris_brown` without opening the file `test`.

```
sed -i -e 's/chris_white/chris_brown/g' test
```

If you want to open the file `test` in `vi editor` and replace, then follow the below steps,

1) vi test

2) Type `:%s/chris_white/chris_brown/g`

3) Press Enter

This will replace all occurrences of `chris_white` to `chris_brown` in your file `test`.

Comment: I'm not sure if `-i` option would work in all the Unix OS, because in HP-UX it's showing as `sed: illegal option -- i`, what if `sed 's/chris_white/chris_brown/g' test_1` be redirected to a new file just to make the changes permanent into a new file like `-i` option would do.

Answer (score 0):

With vi you need more effort than with the basic `ed`.

```
echo "s/chris_white/chris_brown/
w
q" | ed -s test
```

You can use `printf` for writing the lines as parameters:

```
printf "%s\n" "s/chris_white/chris_brown/" w q | ed -s test
```