# How to use sed to not delete whole line matching a pattern

Tags: sed

I have a .yaml in which:-

value: "this is the whole line with this text -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword and the line continuous"

I want to delete only **-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword** but it removes whole value: section

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace substring with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194702/replace-substring-with-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to find and replace a string in your file.
See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace#159369

The code your your case would look like:

`sed -i -e 's/-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword//g' filename.yaml`

This makes sed to replace your string with an empty string.

The `/s` option is used to find a substring in a file. Place the string to replace it with after the next `/`. `/g` in the end makes sed to copy that string to your file.
See https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed